# Does the recyclerview/listview adapter have a method called once?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, listadapter

For a certain reason, I have to do one operation inside the adapter. In other words, this process should not be repeated when scrolling. The onCreate method in the activity works once when the activity is opened. Is there a method to do this inside the adapter?

***UPDATE***

**My adapter class:**

```
class EducationAdapter @Inject constructor(
var userManager: UserManager
) : ListAdapter<EducationModel, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>. 
(EDUCATION_ITEM_DIFF_CALLBACK) {

companion object {
}

var callBack: EducationAdapterCallBack? = null


interface EducationAdapterCallBack {
    fun onClickLayer(educationModel: EducationModel)
}

class EducationViewHolder(var binding: ItemEducationBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun setItem(item: EducationModel) {
        binding.educationItem = item

    }
}

@Nonnull
override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    @Nonnull parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val binding: ItemEducationBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        R.layout.item_education, parent, false
    )
    return EducationAdapter.EducationViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(@Nonnull holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)
    when (holder) {
        is EducationAdapter.EducationViewHolder -> {
            holder.setItem(item)

           
            holder.binding.itemEducation.setOnClickListener {
                callBack?.onClickLayer(item)
            }


        }
    }
}
}
```

OncreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder called when scrolling listview. But I want a single shot process is there any method that runs a single time?

***UPDATE 2***

I created a dummy operation (My original code was too long, I created summarized dummy operation). OnBind method should be like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(@Nonnull holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        when (holder) {
            is EducationAdapter.EducationViewHolder -> {
                holder.setItem(item)

                holder.binding.itemEducation.setOnClickListener {
                    callBack?.onClickLayer(item)
                }

                var isExpandClicked = false
                holder.binding.btnExpandProject.setOnClickListener {
                    if (isExpandClicked) {
                        isExpandClicked = false
                        val context = holder.binding.llTaskFaaliyet.context
                        holder.binding.btnExpandProject.setImageDrawable(
                            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                                context,
                                R.drawable.ic_arrow_down
                            )
                        )

                        val headerText = TextView(context)
                        headerText.apply {
                            text = subTask.title
                            textSize = 16f
                            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.marine))
                            gravity = Gravity.START
                            typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.ubuntu_bold)
                            setPadding(48, 16, 4, 0)
                            setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
                        }
                        holder.binding.llTask.add(headerText)

                    }else{
                        isExpandClicked = true
                        val context = holder.binding.llTask.context
                        holder.binding.btnExpandProject.setImageDrawable(
                            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                                context,
                                R.drawable.ic_close
                            )
                        )
                        holder.binding.llTask.removeAllViews()

                    }
                    }


            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to create those views below:
**Expanded View:**
[image: Expanded View]

**Shrinked View**

[image: Shrinked View]

Views should be expanded at the first opening. It should be single time when the view is created.

Comment: this question is waaay to short. no code, "some operation" etc. please describe well what is the problem and post adapters code

Comment: @snachmsm "some operation"  could be anything like populating a linear layout. If the user scrolls adapter populates again and again.

Comment: this is an interesting question, one i don't necessarily have an answer for, but it depends on what you're trying to do only once. perhaps it makes more sense to move this logic out of your adapter and into the activity/fragment ? inside onBind, trigger a callback to the containing activity, where that activity then keep track of "has this operation been done yet", which will just be a boolean value set to false initially and then true after that

Comment: constructor calls once

Comment: @a_local_nobody It is a good suggestion, thanks, but probably it won't gonna work. Because callback triggers when an item is constructed, boolean value gonna change every time when it triggers. The operation should be on item scoped.

Comment: `boolean value gonna change every time when it triggers` no it wont, it is set to false once, then set to true after that, so your logic will only ever run once if you just use a simple if based on a variable tied to the activity

Comment: @a_local_nobody Sorry, you are right. The callback sets the boolean value to true always. Thanks! I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the function on bind method, it should be triggered whenever the item is shown. You can make a simple way, use boolean on adapter scope that will be changed to false after the expand function is triggered. Then use this boolean to check whether value is true, so it should trigger the expand function.

Comment: Oh, this is a simple and effective solution to my problem. Thanks! My way of thinking was so complicated. But I am still curious about the method that was called once when the adapter was created.

Comment: You're welcome. If you decide to use "once called method" then the answer is adapter constructor. As we know that constructor is a special method which will only be called once when the adapter is initialized from activity/fragment. You can put process in this constructor. But it gets tricky if the item view isn't ready to expand yet. So it depends on you. @AlperenAcikgoz